# Log properties not recording in Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, getseq

For exmple, I have function `doSomething(string a, string b, string c)`. And I want to log function executing. I want do something like this:

```
Logger.Debug("Method doSomething executed", a, b, c)
```

to avoid writing parameters in message beacause strings can be very long. This functionality is similar to the `.Enrich.WithProperty("PropertyName", Value)`.
But i can't do this in Logger constructor.
Logs writes to `SEQ`.

Answer (score 1):

`ForContext()` can do this:

```
var enriched = Log.ForContext("A", a)
                  .ForContext("B", b)
                  .ForContext("C", c);

enriched.Debug("Method doSomething executed");
```

All events logged through `enriched` will have the properties `A`, `B` and `C` attached.